# How to stop webpack compile file when it can't find module?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I build my frontend project with `webpack`. I find if I `import` some modules which can't find by `webpack`. The `webpack` will continue compile. Does `webpack` has any configuration that it can stop compile by itself when it can't find modules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes [it has](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationnoemitonerrors), but this includes any errors, not just missing modules:

> Use the **optimization.noEmitOnErrors** to skip the emitting phase whenever there are errors while compiling. This ensures that no erroring assets are emitted.

So simply add it to `webpack.config.js`